# Countdown in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, countdown

I am making a countdown in Laravel with a plugin  , I have the following code with javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('.clock').countdown('2015/05/25', function(event) {
   $(this).html(event.strftime('%D días %H:%M:%S'));
 });
 </script>
```

This code works correctly but I need to show the diferents finnishes dates in Laravel

```
@foreach ($products as $subasta)
    {{ $subasta->id }}</p>
    {{ $subasta->name}}</p>
    {{ $subasta->startdate}}</p>
    {{ $subasta->duration}}</p>
    <span class="clock"></span>
@endforeach
```

How could I pass the date with the item startdate to Javascrip countdown ? Because I recieve the same format in database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this method:

http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/multiple-instances.html

Html:

```
<div data-countdown="2016/01/01"></div>
<div data-countdown="2017/01/01"></div>
<div data-countdown="2018/01/01"></div>
<div data-countdown="2019/01/01"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
   $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
     $this.html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
   });
});
```

So basically you would need to add a data attribute to each of your products SPAN and print the date inside:

```
@foreach ($products as $subasta)
    {{ $subasta->id }}</p>
    {{ $subasta->name}}</p>
    {{ $subasta->startdate}}</p>
    {{ $subasta->duration}}</p>
    <span class="clock" data-countdown="{{ $subasta->startdate}}"></span>
@endforeach
```

And then update your javascript to loop all the elements and use the attribute as the date. You could use the JS code above and adjust, if you want, the attribute name and variables name or the format text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !!  , I need this urgent :D